# Bootstrap 8.x-3.10 Dialog Form wrong formatting w/ Drupal

Tags: php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, drupal-8

We recently upgraded from bootstrap 8.x-3.5 to 8.x-3.10, and noticed that the search icon broke. The button's text now shows up as: [broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr3Ao.png)

This is all controlled in php from these 2 segments:

```
$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
    $form['actions']['send'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Search', array(), array('langcode' => $language)),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'btn-primary',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'submitModalFormAjax'],
        'event' => 'click',

      ],
    ];
```

However, commenting out the top line, which moves the button into the actions area of the form, allows the icon to show up just fine as: [working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acd9O.png). This change in bootstrap has broken similar things in this modal, so have been trying to figure out if this is due to changes in how modals work or some other bug. Has anyone run into a similiar issue or has an idea of how to tackle this? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be with the code you put in your question, that just seems to build an array. I guess the title of the button is generated by `$this->t(...)`? What does that return? How is the array used? Your bootstrap version number is also not a normal number: http://getbootstrap.com All I can find with these version numbers is something with Drupal. Are you using Drupal? Sorry, lot's of question....

Comment: you are correct, this is with Drupal, sorry for that confusion. The title of the button is generated by the `$this->t(...)`, but i'm unsure how exactly this is used or what it returns. I'm still learning how my projects actually ends up using this code as few  people on the project know. From what i gather the actions index of the form appears to be a segment that acts as a footer of the modal, so that the content can be scrolled inside but allow the, in this case 'Search' button, to be visible at all times

Comment: I don't think anybody here can help you, there just isn't enough to go on. What is obvious to me is that we see the HTML code of the search icon in your 'broken image'. This might mean that the HTML specific characters are translated into HTML entities. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity Since there's a lack of essential code in your question I can't tell where this happens.